# How can we access multiple JMS Queues using single consumre in JAVA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

I have a requirement of accesssing multiple JMS queues and perform the desired operations based upon the event we are getting. This is being done on Spring Boot project. Could anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

You can configure different @JmsListener in Spring boot and it will receive message from respective Queue you have configured.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${abcQueueName}", containerFactory = "abcQueueListenerFactory")
    public void receiveQuery(@Payload Test test,
                                    @Headers MessageHeaders headers,
                                    Message message,
                                    Session sessionQuery) {
}





@Bean(name = "abcQueueListenerFactory")
        public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> testQueueListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setPubSubDomain(false);
            factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
            factory.setConcurrency(concurrency + "-" + maxConcurrency);
            factory.setReceiveTimeout(Long.valueOf(receiveTimeout));
            factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
            factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
            return factory;

        }
```